# How to calculate this summation of fractions of binomial coefficients?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I want to know how to simplify the following sum (given $i, n \in \mathbb{N}$):

$$
  \sum_{k=1}^i \frac{k}{n-k} \frac{\binom{i-1}{k-1}}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}\ .
$$

$\binom{a}{b}$ is a binomial coefficient. [WolframAlpha says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B(k%2F(n-k))*(Binomial%5Bi-1,k-1%5D%2FBinomial%5Bn-1,k-1%5D),%20k%3D1%20to%20i%5D) this equals $\frac{n}{(n-i+1)(n-i)}$, but it doesn't show how to calculate this step-by-step. I tackled to solve this for a day, but I couldn't figure out. Could you let me know an approach?

Note: This sum is needed to calculate a complexity of Chang and Roberts algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start by simplifying the summand
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{k}{n-k} \frac{\binom{i-1}{k-1}}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}} &=& \frac{(i-1)!}{(i-k)!} \frac{(n-k)!}{(n-1)!} \frac{k}{n-k} \\ 
&=& \frac{(i-1)!(n-i-1)!}{(n-1)!} k \frac{(n-k-1)!}{(i-k)! (n-i-1)!}  \\
&=& \frac{(i-1)!(n-i-1)!}{(n-1)!} k \binom{n-k-1}{i-k}.  \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now do the coefficient trick $\binom{n-k-1}{i-k}= [x^{i-k}]:(1+x)^{n-k-1} =[x^i]: x^k (1+x)^{n-k-1}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=1}^i \frac{k}{n-k} \frac{\binom{i-1}{k-1}}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}} &=& \frac{(i-1)!(n-i-1)!}{(n-1)!} [x^i]: \sum_{k=1}^i k x^k (1+x)^{n-k-1} \\
&=& \frac{(i-1)!(n-i-1)!}{(n-1)!} [x^i]: \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k x^k (1+x)^{n-k-1} \\
&=& \frac{(i-1)!(n-i-1)!}{(n-1)!} [x^i]: \frac{\frac{x}{1+x} (1+x)^{n-1}}{(1-\frac{x}{1+x})^2} \\
&=& \frac{(i-1)!(n-i-1)!}{(n-1)!} [x^i]: x(1+x)^n \\
&=& \frac{(i-1)!(n-i-1)!}{(n-1)!} \binom{n}{i-1} \\
&=& \frac{n}{(n-i+1)(n-i)}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks for answering. What is the meaning of the symbol $[x^i] : f(x)$? Maybe... a coefficient of $x^i$ of a [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generating_functions) $f(x)$?

Comment: Maybe lost $k$ in the first line of the latter equations.

Comment: @Socho If $f(x)=a_0+a_1 x+ \cdots + a_i x^i + \cdots $ then
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_i = [x^i]: f(x)
\end{eqnarray*}
and reads as aye eye equals the coefficient of ecks to the eye in the function eff, I refer to this as the coefficient trick. Secondly, you are right I had lost a $k$ ... I have edited now $\ddot \smile$